# "An error occurred when creating the datalink channel: No such device (os error 19)"

Tags: rust, data-linking

I'm trying to make a Rust program running on our Debian 11 instances (created through OpenStack) and I encounter the same issue when running (as root)

`./masscanned --iface ens3 --self-ip-list myIP --remote-ip-deny-file /root/ignored_ips --format logfmt -v`

I get this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'An error occurred when creating the datalink channel: No such device (os error 19)', src/masscanned.rs:92:19
stack backtrace:
0:     0x5647d52eaf0a - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::libunwind::trace::h9a6b80bbf328ba5d
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:93:5
1:     0x5647d52eaf0a - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized::hd162ec543a11886b
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66:5
2:     0x5647d52eaf0a - std::sys_common::backtrace::\_print_fmt::h78a5099be12f51a6
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:65:5
3:     0x5647d52eaf0a - \<std::sys_common::backtrace::\_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display\>::fmt::ha1c5390454d74f71
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:44:22
4:     0x5647d5309c1f - core::fmt::write::h9ffde816c577717b
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:1254:17
5:     0x5647d52e8925 - std::io::Write::write_fmt::h88186074961638e4
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:1698:15
6:     0x5647d52eacd5 - std::sys_common::backtrace::\_print::h184198273ed08d59
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:47:5
7:     0x5647d52eacd5 - std::sys_common::backtrace::print::h1b4d8e7add699453
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:34:9
8:     0x5647d52ec25e - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::h393bcea75423915a
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:269:22
9:     0x5647d52ec005 - std::panicking::default_hook::h48c64f31d8b3fd03
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:288:9
10:     0x5647d52ec7be - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::hafdc493a79370062
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:691:13
11:     0x5647d52ec6b9 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}::h0a64bc82e36bedc7
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:582:13
12:     0x5647d52eb376 - std::sys_common::backtrace::\__rust_end_short_backtrace::hc203444fb7416a16
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:150:18
13:     0x5647d52ec412 - rust_begin_unwind
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:578:5
14:     0x5647d50b1b33 - core::panicking::panic_fmt::h0f6ef0178afce4f2
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/core/src/panicking.rs:67:14
15:     0x5647d50b7bbd - masscanned::get_channel::hf4bda9dd40b9d2dc
at /root/canaris/sonde/masscanned/src/masscanned.rs:92:19
16:     0x5647d50bb1b5 - masscanned::main::hce08a8f034783004
at /root/canaris/sonde/masscanned/src/masscanned.rs:292:28
17:     0x5647d50c70cb - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h129dffed57e22b65
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
18:     0x5647d50e500e - std::sys_common::backtrace::\__rust_begin_short_backtrace::hbc735c8ab56b5585
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:134:18
19:     0x5647d50d9201 - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::h03887a2b44e4dbd9
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/rt.rs:166:18
20:     0x5647d52e43be - core::ops::function::impls::\<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce\<A\> for &F\>::call_once::hb1327dc2ef3fecdf
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:287:13
21:     0x5647d52e43be - std::panicking::try::do_call::h4044173225fe83dd
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:485:40
22:     0x5647d52e43be - std::panicking::try::hd8a722c09d156a53
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:449:19
23:     0x5647d52e43be - std::panic::catch_unwind::hd2ca07971cf0119b
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
24:     0x5647d52e43be - std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}::h26d89d595cf47b70
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:48
25:     0x5647d52e43be - std::panicking::try::do_call::hf47aa1aa005e5f1a
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:485:40
26:     0x5647d52e43be - std::panicking::try::h73d246b2423eaf4e
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panicking.rs:449:19
27:     0x5647d52e43be - std::panic::catch_unwind::hbaaeae8f1b2f9915
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
28:     0x5647d52e43be - std::rt::lang_start_internal::h76f3e81e6b8f13f9
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:20
29:     0x5647d50d91da - std::rt::lang_start::h680b1a4cf7c6f49a
at /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/std/src/rt.rs:165:17
30:     0x5647d50bbb5e - main
31:     0x7f74285d4d0a - \__libc_start_main
at ./csu/../csu/libc-start.c:308:16
32:     0x5647d50b21fa - \_start
```

/root/canaris/sonde/masscanned/src/masscanned.rs:92:19 corresponds to

```
fn get_channel(
    interface: &NetworkInterface,
) -> (
    Box<(dyn DataLinkSender + 'static)>,
    Box<(dyn DataLinkReceiver + 'static)>,
) {
    // Create a new channel, dealing with layer 2 packets
    match datalink::channel(&interface, Default::default()) {
        Ok(Ethernet(tx, rx)) => (tx, rx),
        Ok(_) => panic!("Unhandled channel type"),
        Err(e) => panic!(
            "An error occurred when creating the datalink channel: {}",
            e
        ),
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your network interface really named `ens3`? Not `enp0s3` or similar?

Comment: _ip link show_ gives me the following : 2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:a1:ea:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s3

Comment: I've added some debug track : **info!("avant match datalink {:?}",&interface.ips);** to ensure my interface is known before calling datalink::channel. And I got : `INFO - avant match datalink [V4(Ipv4Network { addr: 192.168.50.206, prefix: 24 })]`

Answer (score 0):

I finally deleted my local masscanned repo and git-cloned the Github repo and it worked fine.
I can close this issue